# Как прижать футер к низу экрана?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, css3

Здравствуйте!
Как сделать высоту вложенного блока 100% от высоты родителя, если у родителя задана min-height, но не задана height? 
в приведенном ниже коде тег main надо растянуть до футера, при том чтобы от перегрузки контентом блок не вылазил за футер снизу.
онлайн пример: https://jsfiddle.net/pq9x7gjv/

UPD: 
при задании фиксированной высоты появляется проблема напозлания футера на main, пример тут: https://jsfiddle.net/mk0g8gk8/

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main class="data">
   data
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
 </div>
</body>
```

CCS:

```
 html, body {
    width: 795px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d7ffd4;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }

  header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }

  .data {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .wrap {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #7892ff;
  }

  footer {
    width: 795px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Решение было найдено мной, в данном случае высоту блока main я рассчитал с помощью vh единиц

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Задайте родителю `height: 1px`. А у `main` `height: calc(100% - высота header - высота footer`. То есть `height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px)`

```css
#parent {
  min-height: 600px;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}

header, footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: не подходит, при перегрузке блока main контентом, он выходит за пределы main, а необходимо, чтобы блок растягивался по высоте от добавления контента. иными словами если добавить много текста в блок main, футер окажется над блоком main, а не внизу страницы, как надо

Comment: вот тут видна проблема:
https://jsfiddle.net/mk0g8gk8/

Comment: вы вариант с flexbox не рассматриваете?

Comment: к сожалению нет, задача только CSS, HTML, блочная верстка без флексбоксов, без гридов и таблиц, без JS

Comment: Возможно решение с display:table у родителя и display:table-row у детей, будете рассматривать такой вариант?

Comment: display:table  не подходит, т.к. это табличный вывод через css

Comment: а чем вам табличный для этого каркаса не угодил?

Comment: дело не в самом методе, а в запрете его использования. 
P.S. решение я нашел, но все равно спасибо за идею

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   data
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Можете сделать ваш код запускаемым?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, сейчас убегаю. Пример работы данного решения можете увидеть на https://mobidevices.ru

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov зачем вы добавили неправильную разметку к моему решению?

Comment: Взял ту, которая с ответа. А если у вас другая разметка почему вы её не указали?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот мой ответ, если же ето не то, то отпишите и я удалю ответ.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</div>  

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

section {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```